# Schedule Issue in Logic-Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

the scheduler trigger in logic-app is not  Triggering  as per the schedule

I want to Schedule every-Day b/w 6-10 pm It is Scheduling Manually

please check this below Image for better understanding

[Scheduler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjRg4.jpg)

please share your Ideas on this

Comment: I test in my side, it works fine. Could you please check if the time matches the "Time zone" which you selected ?

Comment: And also please check if the logic app is disabled ?

Comment: Its not Disabled How to check the start time with the Time Zone can you share your logic-app work flow

Comment: No, I don't mean the start time. I mean you mentioned the logic app was not triggered, maybe because the trigger time matches the time zone you selected but not your computer local time.

Comment: May I know if your computer is in UTC+05:30 time zone ?

Comment: And I'm a little confused about your requirement. You mentioned want to schedule every day between 6-10 pm. But the screenshot you provided shows you specified 6 and 5 every day. Could you please articulate your needs ?

Comment: Yes In Screenshot I have Mentioned   5-6 pm every day but actual requirement is 6-10 pm every day

Comment: My system is in UTC+05:30 Time Zone

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZF3Y.png) is my logic app. I'm in UTC+8:00 time zone, my local time is about 14:37. I select same time zone with yours in schedule, your local time is about 12:07. The logic was triggered success just now.

Comment: And you need to know, in your screenshot you specified 5,6 is AM but not PM. If you want 5,6 PM, you should specify 17, 18

Comment: can you mention the start time and then try to trigger

Comment: If you didn't specify start time, the schedule will take effect when you click "Save" button.

Comment: Did you specify the start time ? The screenshot shows you didn't specify start time.

Comment: I have mentioned Start-Time in my present logic-app that was not making an initial effect to the recurrence  trigger now it is working as expected Thank You

Comment: Maybe you specify the start time in format `2020-09-18T14:00:00Z` with an extra `Z`, it matches UTC time. If you want the start time match the time zone you selected, you should specify it in format `2020-09-18T14:00:00`(without `Z`).

Comment: When the UTC time is up to the time you specified, the schedule take effect. Could you please check if it is the cause of your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarize from the comments, OP mentioned start time was not making an initial effect. According to this information, it is high probability that below is the cause of the problem:

The cause is the format of start time in "**Recurrence**", if we specify the start time in the format of `2020-09-18T14:00:00Z`(with an extra `Z`), it will apply UTC time zone (so the start time didn't take effect at the beginning and when the UTC time is up to local time, the start time take effect). If we want the start time applies the time zone which we selected, we should specify it in the format like `2020-09-18T14:00:00`(without `Z`).

[image]